# NOT targeting iPad with new 4.0 iPhone Application, error on submission

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store

I'm about ready to pull my hair out.  I've built a new app but opted to go iOS4 only and exclude an iPad target.  I keep getting this error when submitting:

"This bundle is invalid. An application targeting the iPad device family may not require a iOS Deployment Target of 4.0 or 4.1, which support iPhone and iPod only."

I don't know what it's talking about.  My base SDK is 4.1, my targeted SDK is 4.0.  I included an iPad icon at 72x72 because it first started complaining that I didn't have an iPad icon.  Now it's complaining that iPad doesn't support 4.0 yet.

I'm not sure what to do.  Is there something in my .plist I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the **Targeted Device Family** setting in your Target settings. It is probably set to 'iPhone/iPad' and not to 'iPhone'.